# MIME type handling in uploading a serving files through attachment_fu

Tags: ruby-on-rails, upload, mime, attachment-fu

I'm currently using attachment_fu to handle file uploads, and while the plugin provides a nice  catchall for images in `:content_type => [:image]`, nothing similar seems to exist for broader buckets. None of the uploads will be executed, per se, only saved to disk and served back at a later time. So a few related questions.

1. Is there any harm in accepting all
   MIME types?  Putting `:content_type => nil` seems to do it.
2. Does Rails/attachment_fu/some other
   plugin provide a formidable listing
   and grouping of MIME types?
3. How can I implement specific
   callbacks for certain MIME types?
4. I stumbled on mimetype-fu to parse
   the [application/octet-stream](http://github.com/mattetti/mimetype-fu)
   uploads. Is this the best practice?
5. Is there, perhaps, a way in Rails to
   delegate MIME type determination
   when delivering the files to
   subsequent users to the server?

Many cheers for any help/guidance.